Complex of groups of an orbifold
I have just started to look a bit into orbifolds. The English Wikipedia page mentions that there is a complex of groups associated to an (effective) orbifold.
However I couldn't manage to find the cocycle relation (guaranteeing associativity). (Let us take the conventions from Wikipedia to discuss this matter).
Also the transition elements $g_{ijk} \in \Gamma_k$ is given by a chain of inclusion $U_i \subset U_j \subset U_k$. I was wondering if there was something more "symmetrical" corresponding to a triple overlap $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k$ rather than a chain of inclusions.
Any help or advice on this ? Thank you !
